# Is it possible to handle object in the body of RouteComponentProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a config route file like this

```
<PrivateRoute
   exact
   path="/:id/:title"
   parentClass="theme-1"
   component={PostOnePage} />
```

and have a component like this

```
type TParams = { id: string, title: string};

const PostOnePage = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<TParams>) => {
    const id = match.params.id;
    const title = match.params.title;
    return <></>;
}
```

the id and title were extracted from an object containing the id, title, content, category, date ...

So, Instead of creating a request to get all these data, I would love to know if I can pass the whole of the object in the body.

Any answer I will appreciate.

Comment: What is the whole data and what is the body? Can you explain a little more?

Comment: @RanuVijay Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. In the Main Page of the website I do a request and fetched the data, this is what I meant with the "whole data". I manipulated this data to show the user photo and title. What I need to do is when the user clicked on the photo I can move him to another component without doing another request. So I need to handle every (photo and title) with his object. I hope this is clear

Comment: useReducer hook is used for the same purpose and even you can use Redux. Try learn these two, these are very important for React development.

Comment: Search for how to pass data with Link in react, you will get your answer. So when the user clicks on the image it goes to the user profile page and here with the link you can pass the whole data.

Comment: Gotch, Thanks a lot :)